# How to add new data to JSON if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript

I am new to using JSON files in my code, and I'm trying to set up a system where there are two values:

"User" and "Points"

What I intend the JSON file to be *approximately* formatted as is:

```
{
Aurora: 5,
Jack: 2,
Ariel: 10,
}
```

Honestly, any format will do. If there's already an "Aurora", it'll either add or remove points to the value. If there's a new user that inputs a command, lets say "John", it'll create a new JSON line (or array):

```
{
Aurora: 5,
Jack: 2,
Ariel: 10,
John: 0,
}
```

So on so forth, with each new user adding a new line to the JSON file with the respective points. How can I achieve this?

Comment: This isn't json and isn't specific to node.js

Comment: Yes but I am currently using node.js for this project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different approaches to this. A simple approach is to hold the data as a constant and manipulate it on every update. Using a function to do this is probably the most straight-forward approach as the function can then be called whenever new data has to be added to the data object.

```js
const data = {
  Aurora: 5,
  Jack: 2,
  Ariel: 10,
};

function addToData(name, value) {  
  data[name] = data[name] ? data[name] + value : value;
}

addToData('John', 3);
addToData('Aurora', 2);

console.log(data);
```

Another approach is to use a pure function that doesn't manipulate the original value and returns a new data object. This reduces the chance of there being unwanted side-effects, but a little more copmlex.

```js
let dataObj = {
  Aurora: 5,
  Jack: 2,
  Ariel: 10,
};

function addToData(data, name, value) {
  const newData = {
    ...data
  };
  newData[name] = data[name] ? data[name] + value : value;
  return newData;
}

dataObj = addToData(dataObj, 'John', 3);
dataObj = addToData(dataObj, 'Aurora', 2);

console.log(dataObj);
```

Comment: I'll try this one out  as well

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And in order to write it into the .json file, I just have  to do a ``fs.writeFileSync("./points.json", data)``?

Comment: You'll probably need to stringify the data first - `fs.writeFileSync("./points.json", JSON.stringify(data))`